# How to change filter WooCommerce products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to change filter WooCommerce product archive by custom attributes.
For example, the search now falls in categories and i want to change it in country"tags" like search all products in united-states

this woocomere php code

```
add_filter( 'get_product_search_form' , 'froday_custom_product_searchform' );

function froday_custom_product_searchform( $form ) {

    $form = '
    <form class="search-form woocommerce-product-search" role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ) . '">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="query form-control input-lg search-input" type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" placeholder="' . esc_html__( 'Enter Keyword Here ...', 'froday' ) . '" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-search btn-block">
                            <i class="fa fa-search font-16"></i>
                        </button>
                        <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>';

    return $form;
}
```

Comment: can you please rephrase your question as i didn't understand your question what exactly do you want? do you want to search only in tags?

Comment: i want search only in country is a tags

Comment: so please  ? YOU Can help me?

Comment: do you want the search only in tags without category or product name?

Comment: or you just the tag to be searchable